# Тип char не является ни signed, ни unsigned?

Tags: c++, char, типы-данных, signed, unsigned

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
 
int main() {
    if constexpr (std::is_signed_v<char>) {
        std::cout << std::is_same_v<char, signed char>;
    } else {
        std::cout << std::is_same_v<char, unsigned char>;
    }
}
```

Почему этот код выводит 0? Как `char` может быть ни одним, ни другим? Это же логику нарушает!

Comment: Типов `char` три : `char` , `signed char` , `unsigned char`. У первого типа понятие `signed/unsigned` отсутствует.

Comment: @AlexGlebe почему так? `std::is_signed_v<char>` тогда бы не выводил ничего

Comment: наоборот,  логика нарушится, если типы не разные. Зачем тогда нужен один из них?

Comment: @Evangeleon потому что `std::is_signed_v<char>` просто проверяет, что (char)-1 < (char)0

Comment: @ARHovsepyan `std::is_same_v<int, signed int>;` у меня выводит 1, так что ничего не нарушает, а вот код в вопросе нарушает, потому что закон исключённого третьего

Comment: На одних машинах char определен как знаковый, а на других _ как  без знаковый(зависит от архитектуры), т.е. это тип, который может быть как знаковым,, так и без знаковым, но   это не псевдоним signed/unsigned char.  А int всегда без знаковый

Comment: Так и есть, это во всех учебниках написано, и в мануалах, и в таблицах референсов. Везде.

Comment: `char` - это символ, `signed char` и `unsigned char` - число, вот и вся логика. Но вообще лучше избегать `signed char` и `unsigned char`, и писать `std::int8_t` и `std::uint8_t`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По историческим причинам тип `char` стоит несколько особняком. В стандарте прописано, что он может не совпадать ни с `signed char` ни с `unsigned char`.

Закон исключения третьего тут не работает, потому что `signed char` и `unsigned char` - это не `char` с пометкой `signed`/`unsigned`, это отдельные типы со сложным названием.

Comment: Что значит "что он может не совпадать ни с signed char ни с unsigned char"? В стандарте сказано, что `char` - это отдельный тип, который использует в качестве подлежащего типа либо `signed char`, либо `unsigned char`, то есть, не смотря на то, что это отдельный тип, он будет совпадать по представлению с одним из них.

Comment: он будет совпадать по представлению, не будет считаться синонимом.

Comment: @Croessmah, в старых версиях стандарта (80-х годов) `char` мог быть реализован через `int`, на платформах, где 16-битная логика быстрее 8-битной.

Comment: @KoVadim у меня об этом написано, - "char - это отдельный тип"

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#7

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, да и сейчас ни что не мешает так сделать... но с точки зрения языка это всё равно будут разные типы...

Comment: @Croessmah  так кто же спорит.

Comment: @KoVadim я думал вы мне об этом сообщаете. )